# two- way bind isolated scope is not working in custom directive - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

recently I migrated my angular version 1.2 to 1.5.x

I'm facing issue where the isolated scope elements are not binding in custom directive. I can't able to see `$scope.menuitems` when I debug, which causes the `menu.menuitems` as "`undefined`".

```
    Directive:
    angular.module('myapp')
            .directive('menuSelect', menuSelect);
        function menuSelect() {
            var directive = {
                link: linkFunc,
                controller: menuselectController,
                controllerAs: 'menu',
                restrict: 'A',
                replace: true,
                bindToController: true,
                require: '^form',
                scope: {
                    menuitems: '=',
                    showError: '=',
                    ismenuSelectionAllowed: '=',
                    onMenuitemChange: '&',

                },
                templateUrl: 'scripts/NavMenu/menuSelect/menuSelect.html'
            };
            return directive;
            function linkFunc(scope, el, attr, frm) {
                var menu = scope.menu;
                menu.menuForm = frm;
                menu.selectmenu = function() {
                    menu.menuSelectionChanged();
                };
            }
        }
    menuselectController.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];
        function menuselectController($scope, $filter) {
            var menu = this;
            var watcher2, categories = null;
            menu.menuitems = $scope.menuitems;  //I'm seeing the $scope doesn't bind the isolated elements.
            menu.filter = null;
            menu.selected = null;
            menu.addFeature = addFeature;
            menu.removeFeature = removeFeature;
            -----
        -----
    }
```

HTML where the directive is calling:

```
    <div data-menu-select data-menuitems="menuitems" data-show-error="formAction=='Submit'"
                             data-is-menu-selection-allowed="menuSelectionAllowed"
                             data-on-menuitem-change="featureChanged()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the **controller as** syntax. In this case your isolated scope proparties will be bound to **this** in your controller and also to **$scope.menu**, so you don't need this line

```
menu.menuitems = $scope.menuitems;
```

it just makes **menu.menuitems** undefined, just remove this line or debugg to see that before the line **menu.menuitems** already contains the value you passed in **data-menuitems** attribute in html template. Read more about controller as syntax here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

So it will be more like

```
function menuselectController($scope, $filter) {
  var menu = this;
  var watcher2, categories = null;
  menu.filter = null;
  menu.selected = null;
  menu.addFeature = addFeature;
  menu.removeFeature = removeFeature;
  ----------
}
```

See also this quick codepen I did to demonstrate that **menu.menuitems** already contains what you need, it shows an alert so you can see what is the value. It uses angular 1.5.5.

http://codepen.io/kmlzjc/pen/oLPQxa